# if else Function R

Tags: r, if-statement

Greetings R profesionales,

Having a lot of trouble with using if function in R, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am trying to add another column onto the 'p5' data frame, each number in the 'position' column represents a single mutation in a chromosome, I want the new column to show the functional domains of the mutations i.e. 'Z-disk', 'I-band etc. 
I've tried multiple variations of code and keep on getting this error:

> the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

```
p5$Functional.Domain <- if (p5$position < 179400576) {
    as.character("M-Band")
}
else if (p5$position < 179483218) {
    as.character("A-Band")
}
else if (p5$position < 179639929) {
    as.character("I-Band")
}
else {
    as.character("Z-disk")
}
```

dput():

```
structure(list(p4.position = c(179395822, 179400405, 179401029, 
179403522, 179403566, 179404286, 179404491, 179406990, 179408239, 
179410544, 179410799, 179411339, 179412245, 179412902, 179413187, 
179414153, 179414506, 179416474, 179416530, 179416531, 179417723, 
179418418, 179419765, 179422231, 179422249, 179422457, 179422725, 
179423314, 179424036, 179424398, 179424496, 179424782, 179425091, 
179426073, 179426074, 179427963, 179428086, 179428871, 179429468, 
179429849, 179430371, 179430544, 179432420, 179433213, 179433407, 
179433665, 179433758, 179434009, 179435468, 179438874, 179440067, 
179440319, 179441015, 179441649, 179441870, 179442238, 179442324, 
179442793, 179443339, 179444429, 179444661, 179452242, 179452411, 
179452435, 179453427, 179454576, 179454957, 179455112, 179455162, 
179456704, 179457005, 179457392, 179458075, 179458085, 179462634, 
179463684, 179466263, 179469477, 179469738, 179470359, 179471841, 
179472127, 179472155, 179472209, 179477004, 179477169, 179477885, 
179478861, 179478864, 179481600, 179485012, 179485829, 179487411, 
179497039, 179497076, 179498055, 179506963, 179558736, 179591957, 
179604264, 179605063, 179605941, 179632576, 179634455, 179644174, 
179658189, 179658211)), .Names = "p4.position", row.names = c(NA, 
-107L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Use `ifelse` instead like `ifelse(d$p4.position < 179400576, "M-Band", 
            ifelse(d$p4.position < 179483218, "A-Band", 
                   ifelse(d$p4.position < 179639929,"I-Band","Z-disk" )))`

Comment: It's not an error, and the message looks pretty straight forward. Please read `?\`if\`` and the arguments its accepting. And, no, don't use embedded `ifelse` statements. Vectorize, such as `c("M-Band", "A-Band", "I-Band", "Z-disk")[findInterval(df$p4.position, c(-Inf, 179400576, 179483218, 179639929, Inf))]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use if statements like that. R has a very easy way of doing this type of adjustment.

With base R:

```
p5$functional.domain<- "Z-disk" #making everything in this 
                                #column a z disk since you 
                                #have it as the final else

p5$functional.domain[p5$position < 179483218] <- "A-band"

... # Continue for all other combinations
```

You can continue this for each number combination, not typing since I think the point is made. Let me know if you have any quesitons.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of base `if` and `else` is not vectorized by default, hence the warning message.  But the `ifelse` function is vectorized, and that would be one option.  However, the `dplyr` library offers a very handy function `case_when`:

```
library(dplyr)

p5$Functional.Domain <- case_when(
    p5$position < 179400576 ~ "M-Band",
    p5$position < 179483218 ~ "A-Band",
    p5$position < 179639929 ~ "I-Band"
    TRUE ~ "Z-disk"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `dplyr::mutate()` to add a new variable with `case_when()` to handle the conditional statements:

```
p5 <- p5 %>%
    dplyr::mutate(Functional.Domain = case_when(
        position < 179400576 ~ as.character('M-Band'),
        position < 179483218 ~ as.character('A-Band'),
        position < 179639929 ~ as.character('I-Band'),
        TRUE ~ as.character('Z-disk')))
```

Comment: hi when I try this code, i get the following error: Error: could not find function "case_when",

Comment: i also get the following message when I library 'dplyr' :Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter, lag

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

Warning message:
package ‘dplyr’ was built under R version 3.0.3

Comment: You probably have a really old version of dplyr installed. The error message says that when you last updated dplyr, you were using R version 3.0.3 -- the current version is 3.4.3. Try updating using `install.packages(dplyr)` or `update.packages()`.